# Tmux randomly resizing panes when not actively used

Tags: tmux

I spend most of my development time in fullscreen tmux (3.2a). In this setup, I have several windows, each divided into several panes on a 32" 4k display (various arrangements in each window).

I've noticed for a while that panes resize seemingly randomly, but much more with horizontally split panes. For a several years, my "main" window has 3 column panes, with the right column having 3 terminals up-to-down. The top right is a shell script that loops infinitely with some information displayed interspersed with `sleep` and `clear` calls. The bottom right is htop. The idea is that both the info panes are updating themselves even if I don't run anything (like when I'm asleep at night).

Commonly, but not according to any obvious pattern, these horizontal splits get taller or shorter. But I think those two only get taller (my script is meant to show exactly 5 lines; htop is about 18 in my preferences, but occasionally I deliberately expand or shrink it). About half the time, when I wake up in the morning, I find my info script has a too-large pane, and resize it to what it's supposed to be.

This is an oddity, but not all that hard to work around. A few seconds first thing to adjust sizes (sometimes a few seconds during the day too, a few times.. but far less often than the minute or so between clear/sleep calls). Less often htop resizes its pane.

For the last month, I have another window for a consulting job. In that window, I have some panes that are logins to docker containers that show server outputs and similar that I wish to follow. Some additional panes are larger, and where I run vim or shell commands. The docker containers I've shelled into update frequently with various status messages. I also follow `docker stats` in one of the panes (i.e. it runs on the host, but like htop frequently updates display, presumably using curses or something similar).

In this newer window, the random resizing is more-or-less constant. Enough to be distracting and annoying. I can launch the docker login in one of these panes, and have it resize within seconds. Mostly those panes used to follow server messages shrink to one line high pretty quickly, but sometimes they grow instead. The one line version is actually kinda OK, since it's like an accordion fold of information I don't need to look at constantly. However, I'd obviously rather be able to *choose* when to fold rather than it happening at random. As far as I can tell, once folded to the single-line height, they don't randomly grow again.

Any idea what causes this, or if there is anything I can change/configure to make it stop happening?

- Pop!_OS 22.04 LTS (X11)
- uname -a: Linux kdm-desktop 6.1.11-76060111-generic #202302091138~1675975749~22.04~f771a7f SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Thu F x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
- terminal: GnomeTerm Version 3.44.0

Comment: ever tried tmux 3.3a?

Comment: I saw that 3.3a is out.  Apparently my configured repositories for apt don't know about it currently; but I'm guessing that's just a question of adding a repo, which I could figure out.

Do you have reason to think it addresses this specifically, or just a matter of "newer is better"?

Comment: it's all about cost. if it's easy for you to try newer tmux and and it works fine then problem is solved.

Comment: Just an FYI for anyone who sees the question.  I've tried updating tmux to 3.3a, and the problem has recurred.  It feels like it's *less* common, but not gone completely.